# convert djvu to pdf

Tags: pdf, conversion, djvu

How to convert djvu2pdf ?

My current approach is :

```
djvups x.djvu > x.ps
ps2pdf x.ps
```

Is there more efficient and better (in terms of output quality, data/metadata loss) way to handle that ?

Comment: You can try these solutions: http://superuser.com/questions/100572/how-do-i-convert-a-djvu-document-to-pdf-in-linux-using-only-command-line-tools

Comment: As I've wrote there : What's a pity that, currently there is not djvu2pdf tool in [Arch repo](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=djvu2pdf) and old ver in [Arch User repo](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?O=0&K=djvu2pdf&do_Search=Go)

Comment: Another way is printing djvu to pdf printer, but you'll got same commands as you tell

Answer (score 4):

I tried printing the djvu file to PDF (using Evince, so it's probably a mix of djvulibre, gtk+ and cairo), but I got a way smaller result by converting the djvu pages to pdf using ImageMagick's `convert`.

For this, you need to

1. extract each page as a separate djvu document (I'm not sure if `convert` is able to deal multipage djvu and multipage pdf that easily), see `djvmcvt -i` (an "indirect" document is a document where each page is stored in a separate djvu file)
2. convert the page using `convert` — we're not losing anything here, remember that djvu is not vectorial, so even if you're generating an Adobe PDF, you're using it for a raster image
3. join the pages in a single PDF (you can just feed them to ghostscript -- for example, generating an A4 PDF named `out.pdf` with all pages from `*.pdf` in the current directory would be `gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf *.pdf`)

This said, keep in mind that

- This does just a straight conversion of a raster image — I guess the only thing you can tweak is the image quality, if it gets stored in the pdf using lossy compression (if `convert` is unable to do that, ghostscript has some options to tweak the output of `pdfwrite`, along the lines of `-dPDFSETTINGS=`, I'm not sure but these may include the possibility of enforcing lossy compression and defining the quality level)
- This does not use djvu-specific knowledge, I guess the fact djvu encodes foreground and background separately can be used to generate the PDF in a clever way that somehow uses that to save some space
- PDF is for vectorial stuff, djvu is way better suited for rasterized documents than PDF.

Answer (score 0):

macOS:

I just want to add that if you open the djvu file with the free app DjView, then you can export it as PDF. It can convert a 600+ book really quick.